# Глобальный параметр в адресной строке CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

Добрый день!

Контент, выборки с БД и остальное будет зависеть от выбранного гОрода на сайте. Т.е. адрес сайта может быть:
1) [http://site.ru/контроллер](http://site.ru/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80)
2) [http://site.ru/msk/контроллер](http://site.ru/msk/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80) (где msk - название города)

Как правильно организовать работу контроллеров, чтоб передавалось название города?

Comment: уберите название города в хвост или в квери и делайте глобальную переменную. например в конструкторе контроллера

Comment: Я имею в виду, в htaccesse, например